# Kind-promotion of data family instance with TypeInType

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting with making a generic free category (Path) and an instance for filesystems for strongly-typed filepaths.  I was hoping the new `TypeInType` extension would make possible this more generalized path type where [my earlier efforts](https://github.com/dag/path/blob/master/src/System/Path/Internal.hs) back in 2013 seemed to necessitate tying the filesystem parts into the category parts, but I'm running into an issue where I don't seem to be permitted to promote a data family instance to the kind level even though it's accepted by `:kind` in GHCI.

I might be missing something obvious; I've been mostly away from Haskell and programming for some time now and even then I was hardly an expert at advanced type-level programming.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here possible in GHC 8?

### The Code

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType, TypeFamilies, GADTs #-}

import Data.Kind

data family Vertex g

data family Edge g (a :: Vertex g) (b :: Vertex g)

data Path g (a :: Vertex g) (b :: Vertex g) where
    Nil :: Path g a a
    Cons :: Edge g a b -> Path g b c -> Path g a c

data FileSystem

data instance Vertex FileSystem = Root | Home | Working | Directory | File

data instance Edge FileSystem where
    RootDirectory :: Edge FileSystem Root Directory
    HomeDirectory :: Edge FileSystem Home Directory
    WorkingDirectory :: Edge FileSystem Working Directory
    DirectoryName :: String -> Edge FileSystem Directory Directory
    FileName :: String -> Edge FileSystem Directory File
    FileExtension :: String -> Edge FileSystem File File
```

### Compilation Error

```
$ ghc Path.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Path.hs, Path.o )

Path.hs:18:38: error:
    • Data constructor ‘Root’ cannot be used here
        (it comes from a data family instance)
    • In the second argument of ‘Edge’, namely ‘Root’
      In the type ‘Edge FileSystem Root Directory’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘RootDirectory’
```

### GHCi

Commenting out the `Edge FileSystem` declaration the code compiles and I can try some things in GHCi.

```
*Main> :set -XTypeInType -XTypeFamilies -XGADTs
*Main> :k Edge FileSystem 
Edge FileSystem :: Vertex FileSystem -> Vertex FileSystem -> *
*Main> :k Root
Root :: Vertex FileSystem
*Main> :k Edge FileSystem Root Directory
Edge FileSystem Root Directory :: *
```

Comment: For  what purpose do you need data families? I don't yet see any need for them.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Interface design sensibilities and probably also being stuck in OOP-think. Nonetheless, I'm still curious why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated your solution. Those `Node` and `Edge` data families are the cause of your error - [data families aren't promoted](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overview), even with `TypeInType` - and they're not adding anything over the following simpler design:

```
infixr 5 :>
data Path (g :: k -> k -> *) (x :: k) (y :: k) where
    Nil :: Path g x x
    (:>) :: g x y -> Path g y z -> Path g x z
```

`Path g` is a type-aligned list of `g`s, such that the `g`s' types join up like dominoes. Or, viewing types as sets, `Path g` is the type of morphisms in the free category of a directed graph with nodes in `k` and edges in `g :: k -> k -> *`. Or, viewing `g` as a logical relation, `Path g` is `g`'s reflexive transitive closure.

In this instance `k` and `g` are, respectively, the following `FileSystemItem` and `FileSystemPart` types:

```
data FileSystemItem = Root | Home | Working | Directory | File
data FileSystemPart (dir :: FileSystemItem) (base :: FileSystemItem) where
    RootDirectory    ::           FileSystemPart Root      Directory
    HomeDirectory    ::           FileSystemPart Home      Directory
    WorkingDirectory ::           FileSystemPart Working   Directory
    DirectoryName    :: String -> FileSystemPart Directory Directory
    FileName         :: String -> FileSystemPart Directory File
    FileExtension    :: String -> FileSystemPart File      File

type FileSystemPath = Path FileSystemPart
```

So `FileSystemPath` is the set of morphisms in the category of `FileSystemItem`s:

```
ghci> :k FileSystemPath
FileSystemPath :: FileSystemItem -> FileSystemItem -> *
```

For example:

```
myDocument :: FileSystemPath Home File
myDocument = HomeDirectory :> DirectoryName "documents" :> FileName "foo" :> FileExtension "hs" :> Nil
```

Note that you don't need the `TypeInType` or `TypeFamilies` heavy machinery for this - you only need `PolyKinds` to define the kind-polymorphic `Path`, and `DataKinds` plus `GADTs` for the filesystem itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I feel I tried this last time around but ultimately dismissed it for some reason, but I can't remember for sure. I'm still curious though if it's possible to do it more like I was trying here and if not, why. Cheers.

Comment: @Dag [Data families aren't promoted](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overview), even with `TypeInType`.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that particular bit in the manual. Seems it would require full dependent types, suggesting it's unlikely to ever be implemented in GHC?

Comment: @Dag I don't know about the complexities of promoting `data` families _per se_, but I do know that [Dependent Haskell remains on the road-map](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2016/07/24/dependent-types-in-haskell-progress-report/), possibly even this decade. [Richard Eisenberg's thesis](https://github.com/goldfirere/thesis) (currently a preview) specifies the design of Dependent Haskell, though I can't comment on its contents because I haven't got around to reading it yet